# How do I remove CLion-2016.2.3 completely from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: intellij-idea, tar, uninstallation, ubuntu-16.04, clion

I had installed **CLion(2016.2.3) IDE** from `CLion-2016.2.3.tar.gz` file. I accidentally deleted the `CLion-2016.2.3.tar.gz` file and `CLion-2016.2.3` folder(which I got after extracting `CLion-2016.2.3.tar.gz`). Now **CLion** isn't working. When I ran `dpkg --list` from terminal, **CLion** wasn't present in the output. I want to remove **CLion** completely(all its files, folders, dependencies, etc.(even the configuration files)). How do I remove it completely?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Run the following command in terminal to find all the directories and files containing ***clion*** in their name :-

$ `sudo find . -iname "*clion*"`

Then delete the directories and files you have found.

To delete ***directories/files***, go to the location of that directory/file in terminal using ***cd*** and run the following command :-

$ `sudo rm -rf DIRECTORY_NAME/FILE_NAME`

Comment: You could also run `sudo find . -iname "*clion*" | xargs rm -rf` to do it in one go

Answer (score 6):

Simple Steps are :

1. Delete the clion folder you have downloaded and extracted.
2. Remove cache in ~/. using the command : sudo rm -r ~/.Clion.

Answer (score 4):

Also need remove settings: `/home/user/.config/JetBrains`

Answer (score 3):

All Clion's binaries are store inside the folder you deleted.

But Clion sets up preferences at first launch, and you may have a menu icon which is pointing nowhere.

I suggest you run something like `find ~ -iname "*clion*"` and investigate what is found. If you are using Gnome2 or MATE desktop you will certainly find `.desktop` files which are the icons you are looking for.

Comment: where I do ~ -iname "clion"  It shoulds bash: /home/alireza: Is a directory, any idea what that means?

Answer (score 2):

You need also to remove settings that are stored in ~/. directory. That's it for Unix/Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you used  snap to install you can uninstall using

sudo snap remove --purge clion